# Prove that $\left|\ln(1+x) -x + x^2/2|<|\ln(1-x)+ x + x^2/2\right|$ for all $0<x<1$

Tags: inequality

I'm analyzing the error of the approximation:

$$\ln(1+x)\approx x - x^2/2$$

I want to know the maximum value of the error if I restrict $x$ to be in the interval $[-a,a]$ for some $0<a<1$.

I know that $\left|\ln(1+x) - x + x^2/2\right|$ is upward-convex with a minimum value at $x=0$. Therefore the maximum value of the error lies at one of the points $x=\pm a$.

Plotting the absolute value of $\ln(1+x) - x + x^2/2$ for $x>0$ and for $x<0$ clearly shows that the error is greatest for $x=-a$. How do I prove this?

In other words, prove that $\left|\ln(1+x) -x + x^2/2|<|\ln(1-x)+ x + x^2/2\right|$ for all $0<x<1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $0 < x < 1$, you have

$$\lvert \ln (1+x) - x + x^2/2\rvert = \sum_{n=3}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n} < \frac{x^3}{3}.$$

And

$$\lvert \ln (1-x) + x + x^2/2\rvert = \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} > \frac{x^3}{3}.$$